# unexpected T_STRING for running mysql query in for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query inside a for loop and getting unexpected T_STRING error. Please help me. I just want to echo the query. Thanks

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("book1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {


    $query="UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where email="trim($data[$c]")";
    echo($query);

    }
}
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$query="UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where email="trim($data[$c]")";
```

should be:

```
$query="UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where email='".trim($data[$c])."')";
```

In PHP string concatenation has following syntax: `$string = $str1.$str2.$str3;`

**Note:** your sql query is not valid. There's extra `)` at the end.

Comment: @user1694724 Add `)` after `trim($data[$c]`. I had a typo in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query="UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where email='".trim($data[$c])."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where email="trim($data[$c]")";
```

Should be

```
$query="UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where email='trim($data[$c]')";
```

You can't use double quotes both inside the string to quote out data, and to start and end the string itself.

Edited to add:

If you want to make it very clear, you can concatenate:

```
$query="UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where email='" . trim($data[$c] . "')";
```

Comment: I think they meant to concatenate actually.

Comment: That was my first thought, too, but I figured that if it's an email field, it should be quoted, and the code might be doing that. I'll tweak my answer, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where email='".trim($data[$c]).'";
```

For queries I prefer the other way

```
$a=trim($data[$c]);
$query=<<<HERE
UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where email='$a'
HERE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Replacing this

```
$query="UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where email="trim($data[$c]")";
```

With `sprintf` preferably

```
$query= sprintf("UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 where `email` = '%s'",trim($data[$c]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
$query="UPDATE users SET email_alert=1 WHERE email='" . trim($data[$c]) . "';";
```

The bracket was in the wrong place

EDIT: Forgot to add `'`